# Hide keyboard on tap on each view - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not going to ask how to hide the keyboard after you are done with editing a textField. My question is : Is there a way to do this on each view ? (like a setting) or do I need to write the two following functions and set the delegate properly every time ?

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I'm developing an app with a lot of textfields (and also views) so I try to avoid redundance code. What is the best solution to avoid this repetition?

Thank you!

Comment: Write your own custom text field (such as `JibeTextField`) which is subclass of UITextField, then override any method you want in it. Learn how to write with this project https://github.com/dhawaldawar/TextFieldValidator. He wrote in Objective-C. If you can't, tomorrow I will write for you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own text field, which is subclass of UITextField. See the simple custom UITextField below:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        self.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }
}
```

Use your custom text field name to `Custom Class` in your Storyboard.

See my example at [Github](https://github.com/thanhtanh/CustomTextField)

Comment: What if the textfield `keyboardType` is `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`? Please also check my solution also. It requires minimal coding and can be used on `UITextView` also. Its more intuitive for user as well.

Comment: How is this an answer,  this only handles text views not all views

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. We can use a `gesture` on the `UIView` and end the editing when user touch on `UIView`. But you must implement this every view. My way is not the best way, but it can solve the question with the re-using ability.

Comment: Perhaps it is the question topic that needs to be changed then,  the method you provided only answers the redundancy part to the return button on all text fields.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do, is put one giant invisible button the size of the screen underneath your text fields,  then when a non text field is tapped, you call the invisible button action to close it.  If this does not apply in your scenario please let me know.

Comment: Explain how this is not a good approach,  this is the way it has been done in quite a number of apps.  I believe one of my iOS books actually says to do it this way,  if I ever come across the reference, I will post it

Comment: Adding a new UI component will only increase the complexity of UI hierarchy, especially with `AutoLayout`. Let us suppose you have an application with 20 screens, are you going to add a button in the background on all of those? A more universal solution is called for.

Comment: yes if you wanted advanced solutions you could come up with methods to handle it across the board by doing something like overriding the touch event on the view controller and have all view controllers use it.  I was simply mentioning the easiest method for a novice to understand.  I can tell you subclassing UITextView is not an answer, because that only applies to UITextViews, no other.  Also, according to this code, only the return button will close the keyboard, perhaps the question itself needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an `IBAction` method to dismiss keyboard

   ```
   @IBAction func backgroundTapped (sender: UIView)
   {
       sender.endEditing(true)
   }
   ```
2. Change the class of your `UIView` to `UIControl` which contains the textfields in storyboard (You can even do that to your view of the viewcontroller as shown)

[image: Setting the custom class]

It looks like this:

[image: It looks like this]

3. Now you can connect the `IBAction` to the `Touch Up Inside` event of this view, in the storyboard, as shown.

[image: Touch Up Inside]